# How can I connect a Raspberry PI Zero to a Windows Computer via USB?

Tags: usb, pi-zero

The problem I have is that I only have one monitor which I use for my Windows PC, is it possible to connect a Raspberry Pi Zero to my PC via a USB connection and then use it like that?

So like a remote desktop connection only without Internet.

I do not have an Internet connection for my Raspberry Pi Zero, so using Putty or something like that is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the method you need, but this link is worth checking out: [Direct connection to PC](https://pihw.wordpress.com/guides/direct-network-connection/)

Comment: As I said, I do not have Internet with my Pi Zero.

Comment: You don't need any Internet access to connect the Pi to a PC via Ethernet. You put a cable between them, set the IP address for the Pi and then use an SSH client to connect to it. It's hands down the easiest way to connect to it via your PC.

Comment: If it's a Pi Zero, you'll need a microUSB to USB adaptor and a USB to Ethernet adaptor.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a serial -> USB connection.

This will give you console access, but not access to the X windows environment.

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable/connect-the-lead

Comment: I need to have the desktop environment as well.

Comment: @Tom The Pi Zero may not be the best choice for you then. As was mentioned in the other answer, you could get a micro USB to Ethernet adapter (https://www.adafruit.com/products/2992). I don't know how well the one I linked works, but I imagine it works well enough. From there, the easiest method to get a desktop environment is to set up VNC on the Pi.